# Going to a page anchor after load adding transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm quite new at using jquery but learning a bit everyday. I have solved many problems searching this web but I can't seem to find any solution for this one:

The web I'm workign at the moment use quite a lot of page anchors.

I have localscroll and scrollto as jquery libraries.

I animated the transition with this little script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.scrolllento').localScroll({ duration: 1000 });
    });
</script>
```

and it works fine whatever I add the class "scrolllento" to the cointainer of my links.

Now the problem I have is when a link jumps to an anchor of inside different page. my client has asked me if it's possible to load the page first then move to the anchor with same web transition.

I have been working on it with my little knowdlege and this is what I have atm:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {            
        var nosalto = $(location).attr('href');
        if (nosalto.indexOf("HistoriaBMG") > 0) {
            $.fn.gotoAnchor = function (anchor) {
                location.href = this.selector;
            }
            $('#historia').gotoAnchor();
        }            
    });
</script>
```

"HistoriaBMG" is the new page and "#historia" is the anchor I want to go inside that page.

and it seems again that it works...

the problem is I have no idea how to implement now the transition as the class "scrolllento" in the container of the link going to ../HistoriaBMG is ignored.

could anyone help me? thanks so much in advance and excuse my english, hope this question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [localScroll docs](http://flesler.blogspot.ie/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html):

> The plugin also adds a function, $.localScroll.hash() , that checks the URL in the address bar, and if there's a hash(#an_id), it will scroll to the element. It accepts a hash of settings, just like $.localScroll. You will likely call it on document ready. Check the regular example to see it in action.

So you simply need to call `$.localScroll.hash()`on `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Amazing. I guess wasting some hours before asking helps to learn, but I feel like an idiot when the solution is so simple. Thanks so much